The mapper returned a null Mono error in MockServerRequest
I'm testing a handler method for which I created the MockServerRequest object as follows
MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.put("/rest/v1/templates/{id}", "1")
    .headers(headers)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(builder.build().writeValueAsString(templateRequest)));


MockServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

ServerRequest request = MockServerRequest.builder().uri(URI.create("/rest/v1/templates"))
.pathVariable("id", "1").headers(headers).exchange(exchange).body(Mono.just(templateRequest));  

the reason for using this calls is that the following object always fails the method as there's no way to get path variables for it
ServerRequest request = ServerRequest.create(exchange, HandlerStrategies.withDefaults().messageReaders());

there's a bug on it Github
So while I stick the MockServerRequest and pass it to my handler
Mono<ServerResponse> putResponse = templateHandler.update(request);

StepVerifier.create(putResponse).expectComplete().log().verify();

I get the error
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onError(java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Mono))

at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failPrefix(MessageFormatter.java:104)
at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.fail(MessageFormatter.java:73)
at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failOptional(MessageFormatter.java:88)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.lambda$expectComplete$4(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:344)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$SignalEvent.test(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:2289)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignal(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1529)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1477)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1129)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:129)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1839)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:891)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:831)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
at com.foo.cloud.bar.template.process.web.api.TemplateHandlerTest$UpdateEndpointTest.testUpdatesWhenAllValidIds(TemplateHandlerTest.java:202)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:194)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Mono
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:235)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    ... 84 more


In your example, there is : .uri(URI.create("/rest/v1/templates")) .pathVariable("id", "1"). Shouldn't it be .uri(URI.create("/rest/v1/templates/{id}")) .pathVariable("id", "1") instead ? (missing id path variable in uri template)

URI.create won't allow {.

Having said that it did force me into looking at the source of MockServerequest again and I realised I should be using .uri(URI.create("/rest/v1/templates/1")). The actually solution to my problem was as error in another service which this handler calls, I wasn't using the correct ArgumentMatchers in setting up it's mock response.

Two changes,
changed uri method to .uri(URI.create("/rest/v1/templates/1")) the null error was from the following snippet in my handler
.flatMap(dto -> templateService.update(dto, request.pathVariable("id")))
while I had mocked this service I was using wrong value for the second argument in the call to `ArgumentMatchers.
